# Django ORM get last record by date

Tags: django

I have a model named PointsHistory.

```
class PointsHistory(...):
      created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      points = modes.IntegerField()
      user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I need to get sum of last day points where record exists. Suppose we do have data for yesterday.

```
today = datetime.today()
yestrerday = today + timedelta(days=-1)
lastpoint = PointsHistory.objects.filter(user = request.user, created_at__startswith = yestrerday.date()).aggregate(Sum('points'))
```

But this will fail if we don't have record for yersterday, i still need last record date sum. how can i do that ?

Order By will not work, because its a datetime field. (if i do order by (date) and get 0 index element i get what i desired).

If need to get SUM of all coins for a last entry day, suppose on on June 13 a record was inserted so i need the SUM of all coins for that day.

I need to make it generic without hardcoding the June 13

Comment: What does your last sentence mean? Of course you can use order_by with a datetime.

Comment: You want all the points created in a certain day or the points created after or before a specific time?

Comment: i want all the points created in a last entry occurance day

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to my sandbox right now, but this should work probably (I don't know your fields, but it should be ok):

```
lastpoint = PointsHistory.objects.filter(user=request.user, created_at__lte=yesterday.date()).aggregate(Sum('points'))
```

Also latest should work as well:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#latest

Comment: but i need to sum point of a single day, and that single day is day of last entry.

Comment: And what is the problem with the above query? the above query returns the last entry, even better use latest as described in the link.

Comment: in case there is no data for yesterday then it will not return any. I need latest record regardless of yesterday or any specific date.

Comment: Docs link seems to be broken.